# What are the benefits of including a pom as dependency?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

The Maven best practice page describes a single use of including a pom as a dependency in another pom;
that of including a shared groups of dependencies:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

I was hoping that you could do other things - like define specific repositories or plugins which would be "inherited" by the pom that you include it with, but this does not seem to work.

What other use cases can you accomplish by including a pom as a dependency in another pom?

Comment: (inserts comment about me down under)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, including a pom as a dependency will only affect dependencies. If you want reuse other things you have to specify it as parent POM.

Note: I recommend to manage your repositories in a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus, not in the POMs.

http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Comment: I thought that maybe the case - there doesn't seem to be any mention of pom dependencies on the maven site - though it is quite hard to search for these terms given "maven", "pom" and "dependencies" are all keywords! We have certain modules that rely on 3rd party repositories and it doesn't seem right to include them in the repository list for every module - which I guess it would do if we are managing them via nexus. We're just starting out with maven and I'm not sure if it really matters though.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I highly recommend to do, if you want stable and controlled builds: list all your used repositories (also those used for transitive dependencies) in your Maven Repository Manager. Usually there aren't that many (~10, not ~100).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to define repositories etc. or issue tracking systems, developers etc. this can simply be achieved by using a parent pom which defines all that stuff. And any project that will use this pom as a parent will automatically inherit all this information (this is often called a company pom). Makes life easier. You can define versions of plugins, dependencies etc. in it.
Use cases for including a pom as a dependency is to define a set of dependencies via a simgle point of dependency in this case the pom which itself contains a larger number of dependencies that makes it sometimes simple to use those dependencies only by adding this single pom instead of a couple dependencies. But usually I would prefer to define those dependencies in the dependencyManagement part of my project.

Comment: Declaring something in dependencyManagement, won't make it a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The link referred in the question itself documents the benefits. As others have answered, it cannot be used for `other` purposes. Cut/pasting for reference:

> - Consolidating related dependencies is a good way to cut down on the *length of pom.xml* files that start having to depend on a large number
>     of dependencies.
> - If you need to share a large number of dependencies between projects, you could also just establish parent-child relationships
>     between projects and refactor all common dependencies to the parent
>     project, but the disadvantage of the parent-child approach is that a
>     project can have only one parent.
> - Sometimes it makes more sense to group similar dependencies together and reference a pom dependency. This way, your project can reference
>     as many of these consolidated dependency POMs as it needs.

There are related examples in [maven dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) documentation.